# Создана ли таблица, или же нет

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Всем привет. Как мне сделать условие на запись?
Условно, я имею

```
var user = await User.findOrCreate({//code});
if (user == как мне понять была ли создана таблица или нет) {
 return console.log('table created')
//code ...
}else {
//code..
}
```

Если создана запись то работать с ней, если  нет отсекать)
sequelize«mysql»

Comment: но ведь всё написано в документации... `In both cases, it will return an instance (either the found instance or the created instance) and a boolean indicating whether that instance was created or already existed`

Comment: @nörbörnën, О! я это читал. Но я не понял мне сделать условие.

Comment: какое условие? в примере написано как сделать `const [user, created] = await User.findOrCreate()`

Comment: @nörbörnën, как мне сделать, если был инсерт. Что бы в консоль приходило "created"?

Comment: @nörbörnën, п.с я знаю что в консоль все логируется, мне для себя нужно

Comment: но ведь всё написано в [документации](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findorcreate)... даже ваш created на insert